# Pyspark can't write to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark

I know this type of thing has been asked before but I've been trying to follow the documentation and discussions on this and can't get this working.

- Spark: 3.0.1
- Hadoop: 3.2.0
- aws-java-sdk-bundle 1.11.375 (based on the [hadoop-aws dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws/3.2.0))

In my $SPARK_HOME/jars I have these installed

```
hadoop-common-3.2.0.jar
aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.2.0.jar
hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar
```

I'm creating my spark session with the following:

```
spark = (
  SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName('someApp')
  .config("spark.jars", "jars/hadoop-common-3.2.0.jar,jars/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar,jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.2.0.jar,jars/hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar")
  .getOrCreate()
```

I'm trying to write a dataframe to s3 with the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'cool':['a','b'], 'fun':['c','d']}))
df.write.parquet("s3a://[my-bucket]/test.parquet", mode="overwrite")
```

I get this error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o295.parquet.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonClientException
```

[People say that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74826245/pyspark-error-connecting-to-aws-s3-py4j-protocol-py4jjavaerror-java-lang-nocla) AmazonClientException should be found in aws-java-sdk-bundle-* so I assume I'm loading it incorrectly but I'm not sure what would be wrong with the path or the proper way to designate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, I think when I was writing my question I caught an issue which was I had aws-java-sdk-* downloaded and not aws-java-sdk-bundle-*. I fixed this but still had issues. It wasn't enough to stop and restart my spark session, I had to restart my kernel and then it worked. I think this is enough to fix the issue.

I'd also added the the absolute paths to the jars as a config for `spark.jars` in my spark-defaults.conf file, but I commented these out and it continued to work so I don't think those were necessary.